# Could Falcon 9 be Caught by the Orbital Launch Tower?

Tags: falcon-9, reuse, propulsive-deceleration

Would it be possible to catch Falcon 9 with the orbital launch tower by its current grid fins or load points that could be added? If they can do this and then remove the landing legs, would mass reduction be enough to offset the added mass of the boostback burn for RTLS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would require new load points to catch of course, the Falcon 9 not being designed for this purpose.

However the real issue with your question is the second part, of economically justify RTLS on all missions.

The issue with RTLS has nothing to do with legs, rather it is the payload hit taken by the boost back burn. Remember rockets do not launch straight up.  They start that way, and fairly quickly turn to accelerate into orbit, focussing on getting to orbital velocity, once they are out the densest parts of the atmosphere.

All that forward momentum and progress needs to be cancelled out. Sure it was generated while the booster was at its heaviest with a full second stage and payload, and during the boost back burn it is mostly empty, and just the first stage. But this consumes a significant chunk of the payload to orbit capability.

Thus for Starlink, it would mean going even further below the 48 or so satellites they are launching into the Plane 4 orbits.

I recall a tweet from Musk suggesting it was as high as 30% of payload to RTLS but I cannot find it now. (If you can find it, edit in here please).

So really your question should be, is the mass of the landing legs sufficient to offset the mass of the fuel/oxidizer needed for the boostback burn.  And the legs are not that heavy, in comparison to 30% of max payload.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant by "this be enough to economically justify RTLS on all of Falcon 9's missions"; if the mass of the legs were enough to offset the extra mass for the boostback burn. I should have made it clearer. Thank you for the clear answer! +1 :D

Comment: Wouldn't there be more potential for damage to the launch tower because of F9's inability to hover, and its reliance on the hoverslam? I remember that part of the justification for the tower catch system is that Super Heavy can hover.